# Office365 Exchange Spam Quarantine - Administrator Notification

Tags: administrator, exchange, office365

Is it possible to setup a notification to be sent to Exchange administrators within Office365 when a new High-confidence spam message is quarantined? I know end-users can be notified and you can set them up to review quarantined messages themselves. But what if all I want is an administrator notification to let me know when Spam is quarantined? Since I'm not finding this anywhere, I am assuming it is not an option, and that it is intentional. That is, either end-users triage their own junked and quarantined emails or the admin does manually. Does anyone know if this option exists in Office365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this under the SPAM configuration page.  But you can add a Transport rule that triggers based on SCL score, and from there do whatever you want, such as sending a copy to an Admin.